# Barclays encryption asp.net (VB to c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to implement the encryption script from Barclays payment gateway, however it's in VB and the rest of our site is in c#.

The script is

```vb
Public Class Example
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

#Region " Web Form Designer Generated Code "
    'This call is required by the Web Form Designer.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
        'CODEGEN: This method call is required by the Web Form Designer
        'Do not modify it using the code editor.
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
#End Region

    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Put user code to initialize the page here

       'The Following Creates the WebClient Object
        Dim web As New System.Net.WebClient()

       'The Header Content Type is then set 
        web.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

       'PostData is then declared as data type Byte and populated with the post data 
        Dim PostData As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("clientid=[clientid]&password=[password]&oid=[orderid]&chargetype=PreAuth&currencycode=826&total=[total]")

        'The Web object is then used to upload the postdata to the Encryption URL and the response is stored in the Response variable
        Dim Response As Byte() = web.UploadData("https://secure2.epdq.co.uk/cgi-bin/CcxBarclaysEpdqEncTool.e", "POST", PostData)

        'The response from the post is then converted from Type Byte to String and stored in the session variable
        Session("Response") = (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Response))

    End Sub
 End Class
```

How am I able to either run this VB in my C# aspx page? Or do I need to convert it to use c#?? In my aspx page, I have the first line

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" CodeBehind="encryption.cs" %>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Essentially creating a c# asp.net page and changing 'Dim X as Y' to 'Y X' or 'var X'in the page_load method will pretty much get you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of shoe-horning this VB.NET code in somewhere, it would be much simpler to convert it; and, trusting you'll take the time to digest it, I've taken the liberty to do so for you:

```
public class Example : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //put user code to initialise page here

        var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            "clientid=[clientid]&password=[password]&oid=[orderid]&" + 
            "chargetype=PreAuth&currencycode=826&total=[total]");

        var response = client.UploadData(
            "https://secure2.epdq.co.uk/cgi-bin/CcxBarclaysEpdqEncTool.e", 
            "POST", data);

        Session["Response"] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
    }
}
```

Note that much of the code is the same, such as accessing types of the framework by namespace looking nigh identical; differences include case-sensitivity, so we *must* user lower-case letters for reserved words such as access descriptors (`public`, `private` and so on) and the `new` keyword, et cetera; also, statements are terminated with a semi-colon in C#.

Further, note some "problems" with the code that you might want to look out for, for example [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) is [disposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), something not properly handled here (that is, `Dispose` is never called.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I've popped that code in and I do understand what you've done :) However, it doesn't seem to be being called. I removed all the code other than setting the session = "hello". It isn't written out as I'd expect. This is the first time I've used codebehind!

Comment: In your page directive, try setting `AutoEventWireup=true`; the problem sounds like your page isn't subscribed to the event, and hence is never alerted.

Comment: changed it a little... the src="encryption.cs" inherits="Encryption:Example". It's showing the session variable now.... Many thanks for the help! :)

Comment: hi Grant Thomas, i am new to barclay payment integration. can you please tell me how to integrate it in asp.net c#.   thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your whole application code is in C#. So, better to convert that Barclays code into C#. You can use below link for convert vb code to C#.
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: thanks for the link - that will no doubt prove useful in the future!

Comment: Enjoy with developerfusion.com...-:)